# How to resume a "zfs receive" on Debian/stretch?

Tags: backup, zfs, zfsonlinux

How do I resume an interrupted ZFS send/receive on Debian/stretch via ZFS on Linux? It seems that the `zfs send -t` option isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You need at least Debian/buster for this feature. You might have some luck with using ZFS-fuse instead, though, but I haven't tried it.